# How to debug MDIO bus scanned failure?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing an ethernet driver that uses the cadence phy chip.
However, my driver is failing to scan the cadence phy chip.

I see that the mdiobus_scan() fails. In this function, it calls -
of_mdiobus_link_mdiodev(bus, &phydev->mdio);
I see that in my prints, it gets the following -

```
dev_err(dev, ".read child =...%s\r\n",child->name);    
mdio
```

Also, I see the following -

ls /sys/bus/mdio_bus/devices/e000c000.ps7-ethernet-ffffffff:01/phy_interface

Here is the standard code from linux -

```
static void of_mdiobus_link_mdiodev(struct mii_bus *bus,
                    struct mdio_device *mdiodev)
{
    struct device *dev = &mdiodev->dev;
    struct device_node *child;

    if (dev->of_node || !bus->dev.of_node)
        {
                dev_err(dev, "Reason....... this is the problem.. dev->of_node or bus");
                if( dev->of_node)
                {
                   dev_err(dev, "Reason......dev->of_node is there..bad");    
                }
                if( !bus->dev.of_node)
                {
                   dev_err(dev, "Reason......!bus->dev.of_node is there..bad");    
                }

        return;

        }

    for_each_available_child_of_node(bus->dev.of_node, child) {
        int addr;
        int ret;

                dev_err(dev, ".reading child now...");    

        ret = of_property_read_u32(child, "reg", &addr);

                dev_err(dev, "read child =...%s\r\n",child->name);    


        if (ret < 0) {
            dev_err(dev, "%s has invalid MDIO address\n",
                child->full_name);
            continue;
        }

        /* A MDIO device must have a reg property in the range [0-31] */
        if (addr >= PHY_MAX_ADDR) {
            dev_err(dev, "%s MDIO address %i is too large\n",
                child->full_name, addr);
            continue;
        }

        if (addr == mdiodev->addr) {
                        dev_err(dev, "This is good no problem at all......");
            dev->of_node = child;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the output as mdio. But, obviously this seems to be not correct since after returning from this function, it fails to

```
err = phy_device_register(phydev);
```

What's the possible reason for the phy_device_register to fail?

Comment: Your PHY interface required any specific Firmware to be programmed? pls check

Comment: I have added more details now. Is it a problem with my device tree? Finally, it is failing to do phy_device_register. I can't make out if the of_mdiobus_link_mdiodev was successful since it is a void function. But, I see it has got child as mdio and nothing else.